# Axis on google bubble chart

Tags: c#, google-visualization, bubble-chart

I am using the googlechart bubble-chart, but I am finding it hard to set the right size on y-axis. Both axis go from 0 to 100%, but most of my bubbles are 90 to 100% on y-axis.Tried to use ticks, but not showing a good visualization. Anyone have a idé how I could do this better ?

[image]

Comment: What is good visualization? Changing 0 to 200% isn't good?

Answer (score 0):

try option `vAxis.viewWindow.min` & `max`

```
var options = {
  vAxis:{
    viewWindow: {
      min: 75,
      max: 125
    }
  }
};
```